# Adding custom social icons to the social media icon block in the Gutenberg editor?

Tags: functions, filters, block-editor

In `wp-includes/blocks/social-link.php` there is a function which seems to setup all the selectable icons in an array together with their names and their SVG code ([lookie here on GitHub](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/blocks/social-link.php#L105))

Is there a way I can add my own custom social links to this block (e. g. XING, which is currently missing) by adding a function to my theme's `functions.php` file?

I tried using `add_action` to add to the `$services_data` array without success. The added icon did not appear in the block options.

Comment: I see no filters to modify that array in that file, have you raised a trac ticket to add one?

Comment: So it is not possible, right? I did not raise a trac ticket yet.

Comment: I can't be sure or I'd write an answer instead of a comment. You definitely should raise a trac ticket and get this officially supported, either that or a github issue on the gutenberg repo

Comment: here it is in gutenberg https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/e33819e59a340ef0594805b56879dd89efb26ea1/packages/block-library/src/social-link/index.php#L105

Comment: here's a GH issue someone else raised: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/34613 and here's a PR attempting to add a filter: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/30749 it looks like the main issue is React Native compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is looking for this;

1. Use the Link icon and add a unique style to the link
2. add custom styles below for eventbrite as an example

   .eventbrite{
   background-image:url('eventbrite.png');
   background-size:cover;
   }
   .eventbrite svg{
   opacity:0;
   }

Comment: How do you add an unique style to the link? A code example will help.